# Store properties separately outside the web project in Spring app using java config

Tags: java, spring, tomcat7, environment, properties-file

I want to hold properties in Tomcat server. I want initialize some bean for development and some for production. What is the best solution?

I tried to use Condition interface, but I receive NullPointerException. It seams that I didn't receive value from my property. What I'm doing wrong?

I place my property file in
 **/home/user/apache-tomcat-home-dir/conf/my.properties**
and add

```
 <Environment name="my_config" value="file:///${catalina.home}/conf/my.properties" type="java.net.URI"/>
```

to **/home/user/apache-tomcat-home-dir/conf/context.xml**.

In **my.properties** only one property:

```
profiler.default=dev
```

And that's how I use my property in project:

```
public class ProductionCondition implements Condition {

    @Value("${profiler.default}")
    private String prodProfiler;

    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        return prodProfiler.equals("production");
    }
}

public class DevCondition implements Condition {

    @Value("${profiler.default}")
    private String coreProfiler;

    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
//        return coreProfiler.equals("dev");
        return context.getEnvironment().getProperty("profiler.default").contains("dev");
    }
}
```

Than I should to configure PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer to initialize properties from file:

```
@Configuration(value = "propertiesConfiguration")
@PropertySource(value="file:${catalina.home}/conf/my.properties")
public class PropertiesConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeholderConfigurer() throws MalformedURLException {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
//        configurer.setLocation(new FileSystemResource(propertyFile));
        return configurer;
    }
}
```

What is correct form: *${catalina.home}* or *${catalina/home}* or how to specify relative path to my property file?

In configuration class I initialize Conditional beans and specify, that this config class depends on PropertiesConfiguration.

```
@Configuration
@Import({PropertiesConfiguration.class})
@DependsOn("propertiesConfiguration")
public class ApplicationConfig {

    @Bean
    @Conditional(ProductionCondition.class)
    public FooInterface productionVendorCore() {
        return new ProductionImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    @Conditional(DevCondition.class)
    public FooInterface devVendorCore() {
        return new DevImpl();
    }
//....
}
```

But anyway I receive NPE in ProductionCondition:

```
return prodProfiler.equals("production");
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Why aren't you using the already available profiles support. Seems like you are trying to bolt on your own solution.

Comment: I tried to use profile, but steel I need to set value of the profile from tomcat property, e.g **@Profile("${profiler.default}")** for spring bean. But it doesn't work, because context doesn't created yet. That's why I'm looking for another solution

Comment: No you don't... Because one bean is active in one profile the other in another. So adding `@Profile("production")` to the bean definition for production is enough and `@Profile("dev")` for the development one. You don't need the placeholder. Instead of your property set the `spring.profiles.active` property and set it to either `production` or `dev` instead.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I'm trying to understand about _spring.profiles.active_ and I'm looking for [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-definition-profiles-enable) but it hard to understand, how it works. It's a system requirement that property shouldn't be hardcoded or placed in web application directory.

Comment: And how is this hardcoded/different from your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to invent your own wheel, try to use the ones provided already. Use [profiles](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-definition-profiles-java) instead.

In your tomcat simply add `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` property to jndi with the value you want `production` or `dev`. Or you can set it as a environment or jvm property.

```
<Environment name="SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE" value="production" type="java.lang.String"/>
```

Then annotate your bean definities with `@Profile` and enable them for certain profiles.

```
public class ApplicationConfig {

    @Bean
    @Profile("production")
    public FooInterface productionVendorCore() {
        return new ProductionImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    @Profile("dev")
    public FooInterface devVendorCore() {
        return new DevImpl();
    }
    //....
}
```

This should only load the beans in the enabled profile. Without any additional work from your side.

Comment: Thank you, but now I receive `BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void com.manager.Manager.setFooInterface(com.core.FooInterface); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.core.FooInterface] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.`

Comment: Enable debug logging for `org.springframework` and see how and where it tries to resolve the `spring.profiles.active`. Could be that it doesn't resolve in from the global context and that you need to add it to the application specific `context.xml` or make it visible to it. You can always set it is an environment or jvm (-D) property instead of a JNDI variable.

Comment: Thank you for giving me a direction. [Here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/using-spring-profiles-and-java) found a solution - add 
`spring.profiles.active=dev` to to Tomcat’s catalina.properties and it works.